# AngularJS сервис $http

Tags: angularjs

Устал писать код

```
$scope.getTour = function () {
    $http({
        url: "/tour/tour/" + $routeParams.id,
        method: "POST"
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.formData = data;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
};

$scope.onChangePublish = function (newValue, oldValue, tour_id) {
    $scope.published = newValue ? 1 : 0;
    $http({
        url: "/tour/update-tour",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            id: tour_id,
            published: $scope.published
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.formData = data;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
};
```

прочитал, что это плохой тон, надо как то вынести запрос к серверу в отдельный сервис(factory) и в дальнейшем использовать одну функцию. 
Подскажите пример

Comment: где прочитали?в чем проблема с выносом?

Comment: прочитал на тостере, типа никогда не использовать сервисы http в контроллерах, а выносить все в отдельные сервисы(factory).

Comment: проблема в том, что не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: [справка по сервисам](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Answer (score 1):

Да, это плохой тон.
Работа с данными должна происходить в сервисах.
Вот, например, сервис для добавления подписки на `email`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('common')
    .factory('newsletterService', newsletterService);

    function newsletterService($http, constants) {
        return {
            addNewsletter: addNewsletter
        };

        function addNewsletter(email) {
            var data = angular.toJson({
                email: email
            });

            return $http.post(constants.restUrl + '/newsletter/register', data);
        }
    }
})();
```

Желательно ссылку на `rest` указать единожды в константах, чтобы использовать потом в каждом сервисе.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('common')
        .value('constants', {
            restUrl: 'http://rest.domain.ru
        });
});
```

Метод `addNewsletter` сервиса `newsletterService` возвращает `$http.post`, который соответственно возвращает `promise`. На этот `promise` нужно подписаться в контроллере.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('common')
        .controller('newsletterCtrl', newsletterCtrl);

    function newsletterCtrl($scope,  newsletterService) {
        $scope.addNewsletter = addNewsletter;
        function addNewsletter() {
             newsletterService.addNewsletter($scope.email).then(function(){
                  alert('Подписка прошла успешна');
             });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: нашел более изящный вариант  - resource

Comment: @ruslik resourse не всегда удобен